# How to track mobile devices around beacon

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, iot

I saw a video about a Pi 0 that has been coded to track the amount of people that are in a location at a certain time to report the data to an app that tell's people if the area is busy. This does not require for the tracked devices to be connected to a wifi.
How would one go by that? Are there specific node modules?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The RPi Zero is able to discovery nearby Bluetooth devices if those devices are advertising there presence.

The command line tool `bluetoothctl` allows you to `scan` for devices to test this.

To do this with code, BlueZ has a set of APIs which are documented at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt

There is an example of how to discovery with the API using Python at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-discovery

The BlueZ API uses D-Bus so can be used with any language that has D-Bus bindings.
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/